# self-signed ssl certificate not being blocked when deployed to Android

Tags: android, ssl, ionic-framework

I noticed that my app, when deployed to android, is accepting self-signed certificates in the server.

To help with the issue I created a snapshot of what I am doing on StackBlitz as recommended.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-login-test

I added the cordova android platform and then run:

```
ionic cordova run android --prod
```

I then set a local development server using django and set a self-signed ssl certificate managed by nginx, which is listening on `https://192.168.0.10/`.

When I access the phone for debugging on Chrome, I can see the login occurs successfully.
I would expect to see an error and be sure that the data was not sent to the server, as it could not be verified.

What I would expect is a result

```
Response with status: 0  for URL: null
```

and a

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

at the console.

But instead I am getting the error from the server of a failed login.

I am running everything on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this issue at their github repository and this seems to be a feature. Self-signed ssl certificates are only blocked when `--release` flag is added and your apk is manually signed.

Here is the link for [ghenry22's reply](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13818#issuecomment-357559224)

Cheers